# PHP doesn't want to recieve data from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i want to create a formless drag and drop file upload using JavaScript's FormData, but PHP doesn't seem to be receiving the file. Am i missing some request headers or something?

JavaScript:

```
if (item.kind === 'file') 
            {
                const file = item.getAsFile();
                const fileFormData = new FormData();
                fileFormData.append('file', file);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "backend/uploadFiles.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: fileFormData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (returndata) {
                        console.log(returndata);
                    }
                });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
```

PHP output:

```
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
```

}

Comment: Are you sure your javascript function is executed (item.kind ==='file')? And have you checked in net tab in the browser dev console if the file is posted?

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES);`

Answer (score 1):

Files are stored in $_FILES array. $_FILES is array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method.
see https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

```
var_dump($_FILES)
```

and make sure that file_uploads is set to On in the php.ini file